# Google Drive API file subscription rate limit (403 subscriptionRateLimitExceeded)

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

When doing some file subscriptions (a.k.a. watch) on some files i encountered a API rate limit which seems to have nothing to do with the general Google Drive API Quotas found in the cloud console.

After doing some file watches i get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "subscriptionRateLimitExceeded",
        "message": "Rate limit exceeded for creating file subscriptions."
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Rate limit exceeded for creating file subscriptions."
  }
}
```

There seems to be no documentation about this rate limit anywhere regarding the queries/seconds/user limit.

I started to hit the limit when doing more than 70 subscriptions in less than 60s with one user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting google support regarding this rate limit i got the answer that not all limits are published to prevent abuse. And unpublished limits are not adjustable.

I have not investigated the limit to get a general feel for it or how often it is replenished. But it seems that it is quite lower than the general Drive API Quota.

The only option is to wait for exponential backoff if you need to burst some drive file subscriptions.

Comment: Don't do exponential backoff for rate limit errors. The algorithm Google uses is a bucket/token. Once you experience a 403 rate limit you need to throttle future requests, gradually reducing the delay until you achieve a steady state.